# using bcp to export arabic comma delimited data

Tags: sql-server, arabic, export-to-csv, bcp

Iam using bcp to export data from sql server 2008 into csv file, it contains some arabic data
but when using -w, the fields are not delimited by commas as I specified (-t,)

Is there any other way to export arabic data & the fields are normally comma delimited?

```
'bcp "'+@query+'" queryout  "c:\test.csv" -w -T -t,'
```

Also can I export the file in UTF-8?

Comment: I am rather sure there is a way to do this. Maybe you could help us by giving us your full bcp command?

Comment: If I remove the `-w` parameter the arabic data becomes corrupted, If I remove the `-t,` the file is not comma delimited, any help??

Comment: What kind of result do you receive? A different delimiter, an empty file or an error message?

Comment: If I remove the `-w` the arabic data is not exported, its empty
, If I remove the `-t,` the file is not comma separated

Comment: What is this data being used for? Is it being imported back into SQL Server or is something else using it? If you remove the `-t` what is it delimited with? Does it need to be commas? commas are one of the worst delimiter that you can choose.